# Is it possible to use mutex to lock an element in a vector not the whole vector?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, mutex, deadlock

Is it possible to use mutex to lock an element in a vector not the whole vector ?

For example, given a vector myVec;
     push back 10 elements into myVec

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
          buffer myBuf = i; // actually myBuf is not necessarily int.
          myVec.push_back(myBuf);
  }
```

Each element of the vector will be changed asynchronously by multiple threads.
How to use mutex to lock only one buffer in myVec such that one thread can write or read an element ; another can read and write another element at the same time ?

thanks

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you have to do exactly? I mean, perhaps more details?

Answer (score 5):

What you want is both simpler and more difficult than you think:

If your container as a whole is unchanged, i.e. there are no insertions or erases, then the standard library containers already offer a limited type of thread safety, which is that different threads are allowed to read or modify *different* container elements, i.e. as long as no more than one thread accesses any given element.

On the other hand, if the container is modified as a whole, then you have almost no safeties at all: Depending on the type of container, you absolutely must understand reference and iterator invalidation. **If** you know that references or iterators to an element are unaffected, then the above applies (respectively to the reference or the dereferenced iterator). If not, then you have no hope of doing anything other than reacquiring a new reference to the desired element.

Comment: Well he stated vector will not contain only integer, so i guess, it can contain structs or objects with more than 4 byte, so read\write operations cannot be atomic, a volatile field is not enough.

Comment: each element of the vector will be changed asynchronously by multiple threads.

Comment: @user1000107: But it sounds like the vector itself will be unaltered. And since you're storing more than just integers in there, you can stuff a pointer to an associated mutex inside of each item in the vector. You cannot store a mutex in them directly because a mutex may not be copied or moved and both is required of objects in a vector.

Comment: @Omnifarious - why can a mutex handle not be copied or moved?  Even if this is true, a mutex in an object would not need to be copied/moved if object instances in a vector were moved around - the object data members do not move.

Comment: @MartinJames: Because a mutex is not just a handle. On Linux, for example, it's actually the memory area that holds the state of the mutex, including OS level detail about who's waiting for it if it's contended. And stuff in vectors may be moved around randomly whenever the vector is altered. There is a reason that you are not allowed to put stuff into vectors that cannot be copied (or, in C++11, moved).

Answer (score 2):

If the vector is initialized at startup it is just like a fixed size array, so there is no need to lock it.
I would prefer an array at that point :) allocated with new[] if you want.

If, let's say, threadN access only fieldN there is no need of any lock, lock is needed when several threads try to access for read AND write the same resource.

If one thread access only one resource for read and write and that resource is not accessed by any other thread, there are absolutely no problems! You don't need any lock.

If one resource is accessed between several threads only in readonly mode, you don't need any lock.

And if it was not clear, in your case, `array[i]` is a read/write resource, while `array` is a shared readonly resource.

If you need to synchronize each element you need a mutex for each element.
If there are n resources accessed by m threads, you need to lock the resources using n mutexes. They are not expensive.

If you have really too many resources you can lock portions of the array: a single mutex will make your application single threaded, but you can assign 1 mutex every 10 items, for example. In this way you reduce the number of mutex but in the same time you ensure that not too much threads are not stalled together.

Comment: each element of the vector can be one or more than one double floating number. The threads exchange data by reading and writing the elements with indicated index (e.g. each thread only needs to read or write the element in the fixed location in the vector).

Comment: I want to add a mutex lock for each element in the vector so that the element can be read or written by only one thread at one point of time.

Comment: Then as I said before you need one mutex for each element :)

Comment: I agreee with @SalvatorePreviti - stick a mutex/futex in your floating point class and create it in the ctor.  Acquire/release the mutex at the start and end of your FP methods/getters/setters.  As other posters have said, if you need to add/remove objects, you need to lock the whole vector for add/remove/iterate/etc but, otherwise, you should be fine locking up each instance on its own mutex.